# method that returns a component of a specified Type

Tags: c#

I try to make a method that returns a component of a specified Type and just cant figure it out.

The components are things like meshes etc. that derive from a Component class.
I have an array of components called "components".

```css
public unsafe T GetComponent<T>()
        {
            T t = default(T);
            foreach (Component component in components)
            {
                if (component.GetType() == typeof(T)) t = (t.GetType())component;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("component not found: "+typeof(T).Name);

            return t;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: See [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-7.0)

Comment: What is making you think that it's not working? It looks like the `Console.WriteLine` will execute whether or not a valid type T component is found, so just because it's saying "component not found: ..." doesn't mean that it's not working given how this is written. Also instead of `t.GetType()` you should be able to just use `T`

Comment: @JamesFaix but how do I convert the existing object of the type Component to the Type T

Comment: I think the whole method body could be replaced with `components.OfType<T>().SingleOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to load a default based on type. I'd use a dictionary instead of a list of components and use the type as your key. Make it a `ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Component>` if there are multiple threads looking at the data.

Assuming you've already populated the dictionary, it would look something like this:

```cs
public T GetComponent<T>()
{
  // var components is IDictionary<Type, Component>
  return components.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var result)
    ? result as T
    : default(T);
}
```

You can also store a Func as the dictionary value and use it as a basic value factory. This is especially useful if you want a new instance of `T` each time you call the function, instead of sharing instances like you would with the first solution.

```cs
public T GetComponent<T>()
{
  // var components is IDictionary<Type, Func<Component>>
  return components.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var result)
    ? result() as T
    : default(T);
}
```

Also, be careful of keywords like unsafe. You really don't want to use those unless you specifically need them, ie you're working with pointers directly and not variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to make a method that is checking types like what is shown in your question I would recommend the following

```cs
if (component is T t)
    return t;
```

This pattern will check if `component` is of type T, and if it is of type T then it will return true and type cast component to type T and store it in variable `t` which can be used in the scope of your if block. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching for more information on pattern matching.

Also like mentioned in the comments, you may not even need a custom method. If you have a list of components you could do this

```cs
var meshes = components.OfType<Mesh>();
```

Which will filter components and give you an IEnumerable of just the meshes inside of `components`, or if you are only expecting a single mesh you could do this

```cs
var singleMesh = components.OfType<Mesh>().SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

the Answer by @JScott works but the comment by @JamesFaix and the Answer and comments by @TJRockefeller lead me to a for me at least more convenient solution

```
public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {
        T t = components.OfType<T>().SingleOrDefault();

        if(t == null) Console.WriteLine("component not found: " + typeof(T).Name);

        return t;
    }
```

this is a school project and I really was stuck on this one cause im not that experienced

thanks for the help (:

Comment: FYI, `T` here could be a class type or a struct type. If T was a struct type, then the default of `T` would be non null. For example if T was `double`, then the default value would be 0.0, not null

Comment: you can force your method to only allow T to be a class by adding after the method signature `where T : class` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters